# LINQ in Razor View Broken for VB

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, razor

I'm trying to use LINQ in a Razor view (VB syntax) and I have the following:

```
Model.TypeList.Select(Function(i) ...)
```

Syntactically, everything is correct; the statement is correct, and the Model types are defined correct.  However, I get the following error within design-time:

```
Error   12  'Select' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TypeItem)'
```

Obviously Select is a LINQ extension method, but it's not supported in my view, even though the DLL reference is there, and I added it as a namespace to the web.config files...  Why is this basic feature not working?

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.0, and note I'm using a custom base page class.  **EDIT**: In the view I am using, I have the following imports:

```
@Imports System.Linq
@Imports System.Collections.Generic
```

My root web.config file has the following:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
   <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
            </namespaces>
    </pages>
```

My views wb.config has the following:

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="Custom.MvcViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

        <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="Custom.MvcViewPage"
        userControlBaseType="Custom.MvcViewUserControl">
            <controls>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
```

Note: the app works when it runs, so this is a design-time only error.

Comment: Could you show your web.config and all `@Import`s you use?

Comment: Done, included the relevant parts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your view file, include:

```
@Imports System.Linq
```

**Update:**

On further inspection, `System.Linq` was properly included. However, I noticed that the Web.config had different values for the `targetFramework` attribute on the `<httpRuntime>` and `<compilation>` elements. Setting those to both be the same, namely `4.5.1`, fixed the issue.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

Comment: I did, to no effect.  And note this is a design-time only error; it works when I run the app.

Comment: How about changing your runtime to `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />` instead of just 4.5, since the `<compilation>` node is using 4.5.1.

Comment: Runtime seemed to have done it... either that, or it could have been having System.Linq in the config AND the Imports.  Simple mistake.  Thanks.